# Create a new list while traversing the original one

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

My task is to create a new list while traversing the original one, and by adding items from the original one to front of the second list, then print the second list "first one reversed". Reverse linked list without using recursion**

Most of my work is in the **addItemToSecondListInreversed** function. I really need help. I'm getting the last item of the first list, which is 9, but the other items are still missing. I feel like I need to do a loop and make it go from last to first but I don't know how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tagSingleLinkedList {
    int data; // A single integer will be stored as data
    struct tagSingleLinkedList* next;
}SLLI; // Single Linked List Item


 void reverse(SLLI* head);
void print_list(SLLI* head);
SLLI* AddItemToEnd(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd);
SLLI* AddItemToFront(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd);
SLLI* addItemToSecondListInreversed(SLLI* head);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SLLI* head = NULL; // This means the list hasn't got any items
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       head = AddItemToEnd(head, i);

    printf("Print list...\n");
    print_list(head);

    printf("----------------------------------\n");
    SLLI* printReverse(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd);
   head = addItemToSecondListInreversed(head);

 print_list(head);
}

SLLI* AddItemToEnd(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd)
{
    SLLI* last;

    // 1-) Allocate memory for a new SLLI item
    SLLI* pItem = (SLLI*) malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
    if (NULL == pItem) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for the new item!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // 2-) Put data into SLLI item
    pItem->data = dataToAdd;
    //3-) Set the next item as NULL (Because the new item will be the last item in the list!)
    pItem->next = NULL;


    //Case 0-) If the list doesnâ€™t have any items â€“ EMPTY LIST
    if (NULL == head)
        return pItem;

    //Case 1-) If the linked list has at least one item
    // STEP 1-) Proceed to the last item in the list
    last = head;
    while (NULL != last->next)
        last = last->next;
    // After while loop "last" point the last item in the list

    // STEP 3-) Add new item after the last item!
    last->next = pItem;

    return head;
}


SLLI* addItemToSecondListInreversed(SLLI* head){
    SLLI* last =head;
    SLLI* newHead;

    if(NULL !=last){
    while (NULL != last->next)
        last = last->next;


    AddItemToFront(last,last->data);


       // printf("%d\n", last->data);
   // last = last->next;
    }

    }


SLLI* AddItemToFront(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd)
{
    // STEP 1-) Allocate memory for the new item
    //------------------------------------------
    // 1-) Allocate memory for a new SLLI item
    SLLI* pItem = (SLLI*) malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
    if (NULL == pItem) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for the new item!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // 2-) Put data into SLLI item
    pItem->data = dataToAdd;

    // STEP 2-) Add new item in front of the list!
    //--------------------------------------------
    pItem->next = head;

    // return the new item's address as the new HEAD of the list!
    return pItem;
}

//printing list
void print_list(SLLI* head) {
    SLLI* temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You already know how to iterate the list and do something to each item (i.e. print it) so why don't you do the same thing for adding to the start of a second list.  Look at the similarity between PrintList and AddEachItemToFrontOfSecondList : https://onlinegdb.com/Nxivl4UjQ

Comment: Your declaration `SLLI* printReverse(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd);` in `main()` does nothing useful; the function isn't called and the declaration goes out of scope a couple of lines later.  You shouldn't declare functions inside another function (declare it at file scope, or in a header).

Comment: Your call to `addItemToFront()` inside `addItemToSecondListInreversed()` (why isn't the first `r` in `reversed` capitalized? Consistency is important in programming!) is flawed several times over.  You should be passing the initialized value of `newHead` to `AddItemToFront()` instead of `last`, and you should be capturing the return value in `newHead`. You also need to return `newHead` from the function. As it stands, you're messing with the list you're trying to read while reading it — nothing good will come of that. And you're not returning a value when you should or initializing `newHead`.

Comment: You also need to call `addItemToFront()` inside the loop that scans over the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration `SLLI* printReverse(SLLI* head, int dataToAdd);` in `main()` does nothing useful; the function isn't called and the declaration goes out of scope a couple of lines later. You shouldn't declare functions inside another function (declare it at file scope, or in a header).

Your call to `AddItemToFront()` inside `addItemToSecondListInreversed()` — why isn't the first `r` in `reversed` capitalized? Consistency is important in programming! — is flawed several times over. You should be passing the initialized value of `newHead` to `AddItemToFront()` instead of `last`, and you should be capturing the return value in `newHead`. You also need to return `newHead` from the function. As it stands, you're messing with the list you're trying to read while reading it — nothing good will come of that. And you're not returning a value when you should or initializing `newHead`.

You also need to call `AddItemToFront()` inside the loop that scans over the first list.

Putting those changes into action, and cleaning up the code a bit, and adding a function `freeList()` to release a list, and renaming functions using `camelCaseNames()` yields:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tagSingleLinkedList
{
    int data;
    struct tagSingleLinkedList *next;
} SLLI;

static void printList(SLLI *head);
static SLLI *addItemToEnd(SLLI *head, int dataToAdd);
static SLLI *addItemToFront(SLLI *head, int dataToAdd);
static SLLI *createReversedList(SLLI *head);
static void freeList(SLLI *head);

int main(void)
{
    SLLI *head = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        head = addItemToEnd(head, i);

    printf("Print list...\n");
    printList(head);
    printf("----------------------------------\n");

    SLLI *revd = createReversedList(head);

    printf("Reversed list:\n");
    printList(revd);

    freeList(head);
    freeList(revd);

    return 0;
}

SLLI *addItemToEnd(SLLI *head, int dataToAdd)
{
    SLLI *last;

    SLLI *pItem = (SLLI *) malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
    if (NULL == pItem)
    {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for the new item!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pItem->data = dataToAdd;
    pItem->next = NULL;

    if (NULL == head)
        return pItem;

    last = head;
    while (NULL != last->next)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = pItem;

    return head;
}

static SLLI *createReversedList(SLLI *head)
{
    SLLI *newHead = NULL;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        newHead = addItemToFront(newHead, head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    return newHead;
}

static SLLI *addItemToFront(SLLI *head, int dataToAdd)
{
    SLLI *pItem = (SLLI *) malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
    if (NULL == pItem)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory for the new item!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pItem->data = dataToAdd;
    pItem->next = head;

    return pItem;
}

static void printList(SLLI *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

static void freeList(SLLI *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        SLLI *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Print list...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
----------------------------------
Reversed list:
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

That looks like what you're wanting.